# printing (NEW) next to the new post for 3 days

Tags: php, datetime

i have 2 tables for categories & posts

the categories table contain

```
id
name
```

and the posts table contain

```
id
name
post
added_date
```

the date stored like (2010-09-05).

when i print the categories by this code

```
$query=mysql_query("select id,name from categories order by id");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

echo "$row[id] : $row[name] <br />";
}
```

i need to print word ( new ) next to the category that have any new post for 3 days only after three days it should be normal category name without word (NEW).

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your query to report the newest posting date for each category. The simplest way to do this is with an aggregate function in the query:

```
$query = mysql_query("select c.id, c.name, MAX(p.added_date) AS last_date from categories c inner join posts p on p.category_id = c.id group by c.id order by c.id");
```

Then, when printing the list of categories, if the value of the last_date column is newer than 4 days old, print the (new) text. For example:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) )
{     
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];

    echo( "$id : $name " );

    $daysOld = ( time() - strtotime( $row['last_date'] ) ) / 86400; 
    if( $daysOld < 4 ) 
        echo( "(new)" ); 

    echo( "<br />" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a database query, something like the following should be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT id, name, post, date_added, 
  IF(date_added > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY, NULL, 'NEW') AS status
FROM table
ORDER BY date_added DESC
```

You could then use:

```
if (isset($row['status'][0])) {
    echo "(", $row['status'], ")";
}
```

That would allow the code to handle other "status" values by changing only the SQL

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$MyTime = strtotime('+3 days');
$sDateFormat = 'l F d Y'; 
printf("Expires: %s\n", date($sDateFormat, $MyTime)); 
?>
```